# how to return model with index from IEnumerable<model> in mvc razor view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have IEnumerable in the current mvc razor view and i want to send the selected element to the child view (popup window).
the current view has as model : `@model IEnumerable<warning>`
i want to send `IEnumerable<warning>[index]` to the child view via query string :

```
window.open("//WarningDetail?warning=" + IEnumerable<warning>[index], "_blank")
```

My code will display a gridpanel of list and the selected element in the grid panel 
will be showed in new popup window with detail. so this is the main view:

```
@model IEnumerable<WIS_3_0.Models.warning> 
warningGrid.Listeners.ItemDblClick.Fn = "selected";

@section JavaScript
{
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/wis.js")"></script>
   <script>
       var selected = function (dv, record, item, index, e) {       
           window.open("/Examples/WarningDetail?warning=" + Model.ElementAt((int)index), "_blank", "left=100,top=100,width=400,height=300,toolbar=1,resizable=0");
          // Ext.Msg.alert(a);
       };
    </script>  
}
```

the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult WarningDetail(warning warning)
        {

            return View(warning);
        }
```

and the child view (WarningDetail.cshtml):

```
@model WIS_3_0.Models.warning


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "WarningDetail";
}

<h2>WarningDetail</h2>
@if(@Model == null)
{
    <h4>null</h4>
}
```

what is the best way to do that? and does the string query work with javascript function window.open? in the controller the object warning is always null !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing server side code (`Model`) with client side JavaScript (`index`). If you need to derive the result on the client and can't determine the value of `index` when your markup / view is rendered, you will need to render all possible values at the server and then select from that list at runtime using `index`.

Something along the lines of this:

```
<script>
    var warningValues = [];
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    warningValues.push(@item);
}

    var selected = function (dv, record, item, index, e) {       
        window.open("/Examples/WarningDetail?warning=" + warningValues[index],
            "_blank",
            "left=100,top=100,width=400,height=300,toolbar=1,resizable=0");
          // Ext.Msg.alert(a);
    };
</script>
```

If your enumeration of items is lengthy, you should likely refactor your code to make that determination on the server and avoid the overhead of passing the data to the client. If the list is short, this is likely an OK approach.

Comment: looks like warning is a class so a json serializer might be a good idea.

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Is this a Visual Studio error or a JavaScript error? Can you provide more code.

Comment: @OnurTOPAL, You likely have a point there with warning being a class but even it is, the OP is only going after a single string value so the code should work with minimal modifications. That said, there seems to be a lot of info missing from the question.

Comment: OnurTOPAL warning object is a class defined as model

Comment: @andleer i got a visual studio 2010 error "The name 'warningValues' does not exist in the current context" in this line 
warningValues.push(@item);

Comment: @andleer the error is fixed now but the data binding failed: in WarningDetail action (the controller) object warning is always null

Comment: I am pretty confused as to your efforts. Not sure how else to help you. Can you provide the full class listing for `Warning`? If `Warning` is a complex type, you won't be able to map it to a single QueryString variable.

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable<>` doesn't have an index property. Instead you can use `Model.ElementAt(index)`. However, it may be slightly easier if you show the rest of your code.

Comment: thanks David
even with Model.ElementAt(index) still get the same problem.
i have added the code to my question

Comment: `index` is a client side variable. `@Modle.ElementAt()` is server side so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proble here is how you render the warning parameter to JS basically `+ Model....` handled as JS code can you try below one instead.

```
window.open("/Examples/WarningDetail?warning=@Model.ElementAt((int)index), "_blank", "left=100,top=100,width=400,height=300,toolbar=1,resizable=0");
```

or some other work around to write the warning parameter.

Comment: `index` is a client side variable. `@Modle.ElementAt()` is server side so this won't work.

Comment: ohh I missed that. so it is your answer then.